# Is it possible to display live preview markitUp?

Tags: php, jquery, yii, markitup

I'm using wyswim editor markitup from here: http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/

The problem is I need to press a button to preview the content.

I want to add live preview as I type in the content. Something like what stackoverflow does.

Comment: I'm using PHP Yii Framework and using this extension:http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/jmarkitup/

Comment: You can do it only using client side and no need of server side or ajax for preview. [**wmd editor**](http://code.google.com/p/wmd/)

Comment: I''m unable to download / view demo from wmd editor. So I couldn't get a chance to try it.

Comment: errr.... your bad luck then. This one was exactly same as stackoverflow's editor(only icons were different lol).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is something you will want to do on the client-side and not on the server (as mentioned above). Also, WYSIWYM stands for What You See is What You Mean - not at all what MarkItUp! is - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYM.

You might have more luck implementing an editor with this feature baked in - though I'm sure it wouldn't be too hard to add live preview yo MarkItUp! - such as EpicEditor (click to edit in full screen) http://epiceditor.com/

Comment: http://epiceditor.com/ looks fine but I don't see any toolbar to add simple html tags.

Comment: Ahh, yes - EpicEditor is a Markdown editor - you didn't specify you which language pack you were using with MarkItUp! Can I recommend using Markdown ;) ?

Answer (score 0):

Not with pure PHP. PHp is **server side** and you are looking for **client side**, most likely JavaScript, Flash or Java based. You can combine these two bo doing JavaScript async requests (aka AJAX) to the server and updating your preview on key stroke